# ArrayBuffer.getElementSlowPath Does anyone face this error?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

In my project I show library image and video to user but in some device I got the crash like `ArrayBuffer.getElementSlowPath`. Can anyone guide me how i can replicate this issue? I got this issue from Crashlytics.

[image]

Here is my code for get videos from phassests.

```
 func getVideo(withCompletionHandler completion:@escaping CompletionHandler)  {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let requestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = false
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video, options: fetchOptions)

        fetchResult.enumerateObjects ({ (assest, index, isCompleted) in
            if assest.sourceType != PHAssetSourceType.typeiTunesSynced{
                PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: assest , options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (asset : AVAsset?, video : AVAudioMix?, dic : [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
                    if let _ = asset as? AVURLAsset
                    {
                        let objAssest = GallaryAssets()
                        objAssest.objAssetsType = assetsType.videoType
                        objAssest.createdDate = (assest ).creationDate
                        objAssest.assetsDuration = (assest ).duration
                        objAssest.assetsURL = (asset as! AVURLAsset).url
                        objAssest.localizationStr = assest.localIdentifier
                        objAssest.locationInfo = LocationInfo()
                        if let location = (assest).location
                        {
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Latitude = "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Longitude = "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
                        }

                        self.media.add(objAssest)
                    }
                    completion(self.media)
                   }                    
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight what's on line 416 of that file? you're getting a `Fatal error: NSRangeException` on that line (you're trying to get an object on an empty array) . Try to focus on what the `iOS SDK` expose as public methods, `getElementSlowPath` is something that the `SDK` uses internally.

Comment: @Fantini i checked 416 line it is last bracket of block `fetchResult.enumerateObjects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some video/ resource is coming from iCloud you need to remove **PHVideorequestoptions** then check your flow . Hope your crash will solve.

```
func getVideo(withCompletionHandler completion:@escaping CompletionHandler)  {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video, options: fetchOptions)

        fetchResult.enumerateObjects ({ (assest, index, isCompleted) in
            if assest.sourceType != PHAssetSourceType.typeiTunesSynced{
                PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: assest , options: **PHVideoRequestOptions**(), resultHandler: { (asset : AVAsset?, video : AVAudioMix?, dic : [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
                    if let _ = asset as? AVURLAsset
                    {
                        let objAssest = GallaryAssets()
                        objAssest.objAssetsType = assetsType.videoType
                        objAssest.createdDate = (assest ).creationDate
                        objAssest.assetsDuration = (assest ).duration
                        objAssest.assetsURL = (asset as! AVURLAsset).url
                        objAssest.localizationStr = assest.localIdentifier
                        objAssest.locationInfo = LocationInfo()
                        if let location = (assest).location
                        {
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Latitude = "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Longitude = "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
                        }

                        self.media.add(objAssest)
                        isCompleted.pointee = true
                    }                    
                })
            }
        })
        completion(self.media)        
}
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure that this is the cause of your crash, but for anyone else finding this question on Google search results:

I encountered a similar cryptic stack trace with ArrayBuffer.getElementSlowPath in Crashlytics. After much debugging I reproduced the crash locally and it turned out that a typed Swift array had an element in it which was not of the expected type. This had happened because the array in question was actually bridged from Objective-C which is less strict about types in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Are you removing a controller on `completion`? The `enumerateObject` function is executed synchronously, if you call the completion before it stops executing, and the `fetchResult` object gets deallocated before the function ends its execution, this could cause issues.

Try calling the completion block after the enumerate ends, and if you want just one result, change the `isCompleted` pointer to true, this will stop the execution of the enumeration:

```
func getVideo(withCompletionHandler completion:@escaping CompletionHandler)  {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let requestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
        let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video, options: fetchOptions)

        fetchResult.enumerateObjects ({ (assest, index, isCompleted) in
            if assest.sourceType != PHAssetSourceType.typeiTunesSynced{
                PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: assest , options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (asset : AVAsset?, video : AVAudioMix?, dic : [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
                    if let _ = asset as? AVURLAsset
                    {
                        let objAssest = GallaryAssets()
                        objAssest.objAssetsType = assetsType.videoType
                        objAssest.createdDate = (assest ).creationDate
                        objAssest.assetsDuration = (assest ).duration
                        objAssest.assetsURL = (asset as! AVURLAsset).url
                        objAssest.localizationStr = assest.localIdentifier
                        objAssest.locationInfo = LocationInfo()
                        if let location = (assest).location
                        {
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Latitude = "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
                            objAssest.locationInfo.Longitude = "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
                        }

                        self.media.add(objAssest)
                        isCompleted.pointee = true
                    }                    
                })
            }
        })
        completion(self.media)        
}
```

Comment: let me try this